# AWS RDS-Aurora MySQL disk space issue and mismatch

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have configured an Aurora-Mysql provisioned cluster with only one instance running MySQL engine 5.7, and so far so good ....

I was trying to identify and see the amount of space that I am/was using and via cloudwatch I got this

[image: Billed Volume Bytes Used]

so it looks like that the size of my db is around 400GB, but If I run a query that analyze the total space like this

```sql
SELECT table_schema, 
ROUND(SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024/1024,2) "size in GB" 
FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Source https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/view-storage-rds-mysql-mariadb/

I have an output like this

```
# table_schema  size in GB
mydbschema  205.74
mysql   0.01
information_schema  0.00
sys 0.00
performance_schema  0.00
```

any idea about what I should check or review?

I have already run an `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the stats again, but include `Data_free` this time.  That would include some pre-allocated space that is not yet in use for either Data or Index.

Also check the size if `ibdata1`.  You may have created large tables (permanent or temporary) there, but then either moved to their own `.ibd` or dropped them.

Also, please provide the number of tables and number of partitions.